# Please evaluate the following integral with the respective constraints.

Tags: integration

Let $x^2+1 \neq n \pi$ and $2 x^2+1 \neq n \pi  \,\forall n \,\in \mathbb{N}$, then
$$
 \int x\sqrt{\left|\frac{2\sin(x^2+1)-\sin(2x^2+1)}{2\sin(x^2+1)+\sin(2x^2+1)}\right|} dx=?
$$
This problem is inspired from a really easy problem from JEE mains standard problems. That problem is as follows:

Let $x^2+1 \neq n \pi$ ,$\,\forall n \,\in \mathbb{N}$, then
$$
 \int x\sqrt{\left\{\frac{2\sin(x^2+1)-\sin(2(x^2+1))}{2\sin(x^2+1)+\sin(2(x^2+1))}\right\}} dx=?
$$
I first mistakenly forgot to apply the set of parentheses in the second term in both numerator and denominator. Later after solving the original problem successfully, I decided to embrace my mistake and explore this new integral. However I tried all possible substitutions I could think of, but I couldn't evaluate with ease. Please assist.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I learned the hard way that you can't just ask people on this site to answer your questions for you without you at least trying it out for yourself first.

Comment: Alright sir, I have provided as much context I could. What more should I show? Please assist.

Comment: This question got upvoted which means it is a good enough question already. I'd help you but I'm as lost as you here.

Comment: You may simplify a bit by setting $y=x^2+1$. But there is no reason for a general function with sin, cos and square root to have an explicit antiderivative. In the initial problem, the function could be simplified a lot by using trigonometric identities. This situation is exceptional.

Answer (score 1):

$$
 I=\int x\sqrt{\frac{2\sin(x^2+1)-\sin(2(x^2+1))}{2\sin(x^2+1)+\sin(2(x^2+1))}} dx
$$
Let $t=x^2+1 \quad\implies\quad dt=2x\,dx$
$$
 I=\int \frac12\sqrt{{\frac{2\sin(t)-\sin(2t)}{2\sin(t)+\sin(2t)}}} dx
$$
$$
 I=\int \frac12\sqrt{{\frac{1-\cos(t)}{1+\cos(t)}}} dx
$$
$$
 I=\int \frac12\tan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right) dx
$$
$$
 I=\frac12\ln\left(1+\tan^2 \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right)+C
$$
$$\boxed{
 \int x\sqrt{\frac{2\sin(x^2+1)-\sin(2(x^2+1))}{2\sin(x^2+1)+\sin(2(x^2+1))}} dx =
\frac12\ln\left(1+\tan^2 \left(\frac{x^2+1}{2}\right)\right)+C}
$$

Comment: As mentioned, OP managed to solve the integral you've computed. They are interested in computing the modified integral with sin(2$x^2$+1) instead of sin(2($x^2$+1)).